# How to create a windows service with an IIS hosted WCF service embedded

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, windows-services

Our project need a new component. 1. It need to communicate with non-WCF components. I would like to host WCF service in IIS + WAS, which is more stable than self-hosted WCF service. 2. Meanwhile, there are many work loads as well as queuing/cache needed for the new component, I want it works as a long-running window service. To be a summary, can we have an IIS hosted WCF service as a part of a window service? Would you please note that I don't want to compare hosting via IIS vs windows service. Thanks.

Comment: If your description is really what you wanted, then it cannot be a single component, but two (a Windows service app, and a WCF app on IIS).

Comment: Thanks for your help! If we want a long running windows service and reduce the IIS limitations, we can have a WCF library hosted in a windows service. If we need a WCF app hosted in IIS to subscribe services, we can have two components! It is not good to mix them together.